# ssl with django, celery, cloudamqp and heroku

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, celery, cloudamqp

I’m trying to connect my django heroku app with cloudamqp over ssl.
Without it works fine.

To use ssl in celery I set `BROKER_USE_SSL` settings variable to `True`.
Unfortunately the default 5672 port can’t handle ssl.
So I tried to set the heroku config var `CLOUDAMQP_RABBITMQ_AMQP_PORT` to 443 and 5671 but both return unknown protocol.
Maybe I miss something or you have a hint.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add port `:5671` to the broker url.

Comment: Then I'm getting a `socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Comment: Sounds like you have a firewall that blocks the connection.

Comment: You're right, I believe I just had the port not opened on my Docker container. Sorry for the incorrect information.